# Split multiple csv files by value from one csv file with c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to open a csv file. Than I need filter each data and generate an output for each value of them.

◘ Example

•Input file = "full list.csv"

```
NAME        CITY
Mark        Venezia
John        New York
Lisa        San Miguel
Emily       New York
Amelia      New York
Nicolas     Venezia
Bill        San Miguel
Steve       Venezia
```

Output will be =

• file1 = "full list_Venezia.csv"

```
NAME        CITY
Mark        Venezia
Nicolas     Venezia
Steve       Venezia
```

• file2 = "full list_New York.csv"

```
NAME        CITY
John        New York
Emily       New York
Amelia      New York
```

• file3 = "full list_San Miguel"

```
NAME        CITY
Lisa        San Miguel
Bill        San Miguel
```

I'm using c# with ConsoleApplication on Visual Studio and I started to read the input file in this method:

```
string inputFile = "full list.csv";
string outputFile;
string line;
string titles = File.ReadLines(inputFile).First();
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
file.Close();

System.IO.StreamWriter fileOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFile);
foreach (DatiOutput objOut in listOutput)
{
}
fileOut.Close();
```

Is there an algorithm that allows me to filter the data I need?

Comment: Are those fixed width columns, or maybe tab delimited?

Comment: In the input file there are the separator commas. What I put in the description is what you see once you open the csv file with excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-LINQy approach using a Dictionary to keep a reference to each output file based on the city name as the Key (there's nothing wrong with LINQ, though!):

```
string[] values;
string header;
string line, city, outputFileName;
string inputFile = "full list.csv";
Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter> outputFiles = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter>();
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFile))
{
    header = file.ReadLine();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        values = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
        city = values[1];
        if (!outputFiles.ContainsKey(city))
        {
            outputFileName = "full list_" + city + ".csv";
            outputFiles.Add(city, new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputFileName));
            outputFiles[city].WriteLine(header);
        }
        outputFiles[city].WriteLine(line);
    }
}   
foreach(System.IO.StreamWriter outputFile in outputFiles.Values)
{
    outputFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: it works, but the first line (the one with the titles "NAME" and "CITY") will not writed

Answer (score 1):

You have written most of the good parts yourself, and now you need to fill the blanks. 
Breaking down the steps

- Read the CSV to a Collection
- Group Collection based on City
- Write the
  each group to separate file

The first step is of course is to read the input file

```
var listOutput = new List<DatiOutput>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var data = line.Split(new []{";"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(!data[0].Trim().Equals("NAME"))
        listOutput.Add(new DatiOutput{ Name = data[0].Trim(), City = data[1].Trim()});
}
```

I have assumed your DatiOutput looks like following as it was not given.

```
public class DatiOutput 
{
public string City{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Then next step is to Group the collection based on City and then write them to file. You can use LINQ to group the collection based on City.

```
listOutput.GroupBy(c=>c.City)
```

Once your have the result, you can now create file name with corresponding city name appended, and add the data to it.

```
foreach (var objOut in listOutput.GroupBy(c=>c.City))
{
    var filePath = $"{Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile),Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile))}_{objOut.First().City}.csv";

    using(System.IO.StreamWriter fileOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
    {
        fileOut.WriteLine($"NAME;CITY");
        foreach(var items in objOut)
        {
            fileOut.WriteLine($"{items.Name};{items.City}");
        }
    }
}
```

You would have the desired result

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var g in File.ReadAllLines("full list.csv")
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(l => new {
        Name = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf(',')),
        City = l.Substring(l.IndexOf(',') + 1) })
    .GroupBy(l => l.City))
{
    File.WriteAllLines($"full list_{g.Key}.csv", new[] { "NAME,CITY" }
        .Concat(g.Select(l => $"{l.Name},{l.City}")));
}
```

The key part your example was missing was `GroupBy` - this allows you to group the data you have read in to groups based on a certain criteria (in our case City).

Group by is a powerful [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) extension that allows you to filter data. The example above reads in all the data, skips the header, uses select to transform each line into an instance of an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) to contain the name and city. `GroupBy` is then used to group these instances by city. Then for each group the data is written to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

I would take @TVOHMs answer to slightly cleaner direction by keeping the same codestyle on the whole solution.

```
File.ReadAllLines("full list.csv")         // Read the input file
    .Skip(1)                               // Skip the header row
    .Select(row => row.Split(','))         // Split each row to array of city and name
    .GroupBy(row => row[1], row => row[0]) // Group by cities, selecting names
    .ToList()                              // To list, so .ForEach is possible
    .ForEach(group => File.WriteAllLines($"full list_{group.Key}.csv", group)); // Create file for each group and write the names
```